# How to run two or more apps in same jvm

Tags: java, performance, jvm

My middleware application it enables applications to run and share data.
I have to run a lot of java applications. (maybe 180 desktop apps in same machine -- UI and data process apps.) When I run applications in different jvm, I have memory problems JVM welded. So that I want to try to run under the same JVM or  ui and data process applications to group and run under the same JVM. Is it possible ?

Operating system is CentOS7 and applications are java 1.8.

Comment: Why do you think you will not have memory problems if you run all these things in one JVM?

Comment: now I have observed that each jvm wastes individual memory and I think that if I can run it in a single JVM, just a guess

Comment: You can tune how much memory each JVM allocates.  If you are so close to the edge that the JVM itself is causing problems you probably just need more resources.  180 apps all at once?!  This seems very extreme indeed.  This is pretty far from a traditional a PC grade requirement.  Perhaps you need real VMs and serious infrastructure.

Comment: 180 apps at 256mb each is only 46Gb ... surely it's cheaper to just find a beefy server with 64gb of RAM instead of trying to re-architect 180 processes that obviously can't even talk to each other over network so they can be split up over several machines

Comment: The most accurate solution is a new architecture and rewriting of applications? This is also subject to a separate cost.

I understand that this is a must, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No unless your applications are already designed to coexist e.g. by being packaged as something that can deployed to shared runtime platform. Otherwise you will have to rewrite all the applications to allow them to coexist (resolve classpath collisions, ensure `static` state is not a problem, other...) and have a shared entry point (e.g. single `public static void main(String[])` method to start all of them) they won't be able to run on the same JVM instance.

Your best bet is probably to review memory consumption of separate JVM instance and tune the startup parameters to reduce it.

Comment: then is it more logical to write down the way you optimize these java applications?